# Angular 7: Ternary operator on binding

Tags: angular, typescript

I am using angular 7. Below is what I am trying in history-dialog.component.html where it should display updated-by-contact ( if exists) or it should display created-by-contact in "updatedBy" column on the screen.

```
<wj-flex-grid-column [binding]="'updatedBy'? 'updatedBy' : 'createdBy'" [align]="'center'" [header]="'Updated By'" [isReadOnly]="'true'" [width]="200">
```

However, What I am seeing is :

If **updatedBy = null** and **createdBy = "test@test.com"** , result on the screen is **empty**. Although when data.updatedBy has something, it is displaying right. Any idea what's going wrong here?

Comment: You should remove the single quotes around the values that represent component variables.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing `updatedBy` and `createdBy` as string here. Use in this way.

```js
<wj-flex-grid-column [binding]="updatedBy ? updatedBy : createdBy" [align]="'center'" [header]="'Updated By'" [isReadOnly]="'true'" [width]="200">
```

Comment: You can also "tidy this up" with `"updatedBy || createdBy"`.

Comment: Also, if you're only passing strings to attributes, adding square brackets and single quotes is unnecessary and makes code harder to read. Prefer `align="center"` to `[align]="'center'"`

Comment: Aaaaand passing the string `"'true'"` isn't the same as passing the value `true`